# ASP.NET core 2 how to skip identity association form?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identity

I have simple ASP.NET app and I'm trying to allow users to login using external auth providers. So far I have managed to implement google auth, however, after logging in a user is required to confirm the email. I would like to skip this step.

I have tried using config with

```
 services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
                    {
                        config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
                    })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

but without a luck. Also I tried to modify ExternalLoginCallback and ExternalLoginConfirmation however I always and up messing it up even more.

Could anyone be so kind and share the actual code I have to use in order to create a new user without the need of confirming his email?

Comment: Do you mean you want to a  textbox which is used to associate your identity account after from external provider ? if yes, that is not email confirm feature .

Comment: Yes I mean that it's called email association.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To skip the email association process , you could modify your `ExternalLoginCallback` as :

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
{
    if (remoteError != null)
    {
        ErrorMessage = $"Error from external provider: {remoteError}";
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
    }
    var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (info == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
    }

    // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login.
    var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: true);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("User logged in with {Name} provider.", info.LoginProvider);
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }
    if (result.IsLockedOut)
    {
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Lockout));
    }
    else
    {
        var userEmail = info.Principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Email).Value.ToString();
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = userEmail, Email = userEmail };
        var resultCreateUser = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
        if (resultCreateUser.Succeeded)
        {
            var resultAddLogin = await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, info);
            if (resultAddLogin.Succeeded)
            {
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                _logger.LogInformation("User created an account using {Name} provider.", info.LoginProvider);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
        }

    }

    // If the user does not have an account, then ask the user to create an account.
    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    ViewData["LoginProvider"] = info.LoginProvider;
    var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
    return View("ExternalLogin", new ExternalLoginViewModel { Email = email });
}
```

That will skip the associate form and automatically use external user's email name .